# how to retrieve data from file on a diferent folder

Tags: python

I have a python script to scan internet with the following structure that I'm trying to adapt to read alist of IPs instead a range of IPs

/ip-ranges

range.txt

/script

loader.py

scanner.py

the scanner.py is the following

```
# Import modules
from .inspection import Request, InspectPaths, InspectContent, PortIsOpen, GetTitle
from ipaddress import ip_address
from threading import Thread

    # Scan result
    class __Result:
        def __init__(self, name, atype, path, title):
            self.name = name
            self.type = atype
            self.path = path
            self.title = title
    
    
    # Return IPs in IPv4 range, inclusive.
    import ipaddress
    def process(iptext):
        try:
            print(ipaddress.ip_interface(iptext).network)
            return
        except Exception:
            print("INVALID")
            return 
    
    with open('ipaddresses.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = "".join(line.split())
            process(line)
           
    
    # Scan IP address range
    def ScanRange(ranges):
        threads = []                        
        # *-- Scan IP range --*           
        for address in IPsRange(ranges):    
            t = Thread(                     
                target=__СheckAddrThreaded, 
                args=(address,)            
            )                               
            threads.append(t)               
            t.start()                       
        for thread in threads:              
            thread.join()
```

The loader.py is the following

```
# Import modules
from os import listdir
from sys import exit

# Select IP ranges from directory
def SelectIPRanges():
    path = "ip-ranges/"           # Directory path.
    files = listdir(path)         # Get directory files.
    for i, f in enumerate(files): # Enumerate and
        print(f" [{i+1}] - {f}")  # print files.
    # *-- Get user input --*
    try:
        file = path + files[int(input("\n [?] Please select country to scan --> ")) - 1]
    except ValueError: 
        exit(f" [!] ERROR: Please enter a numerical value!")
    except IndexError:
        exit(f" [!] ERROR: Please enter value from 1 to {len(files)}!")
    else:
    # *-- Read file --*
        with open(file, "r") as ranges_file: # Open file in reading mode.
            ranges = ranges_file.readlines() # Read all lines.

    return ranges, file.split("/")[-1]
```

The changes that I have made on the scanner.py was on this part

```
# Return IPs in IPv4 range, inclusive.
    import ipaddress
    def process(iptext):
        try:
            print(ipaddress.ip_interface(iptext).network)
            return
        except Exception:
            print("INVALID")
            return 
    
    with open('ipaddresses.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = "".join(line.split())
            process(line)
```

the original scanner.py is

```
# Import modules
    from .inspection import Request, InspectPaths, InspectContent, PortIsOpen, GetTitle
    from ipaddress import ip_address
    from threading import Thread

# Scan result
class __Result:
    def __init__(self, name, atype, path, title):
        self.name = name
        self.type = atype
        self.path = path
        self.title = title

# Return IPs in IPv4 range, inclusive.
def IPsRange(start='', end=''):
    if not start and not end:
        return []
    if not end and start.__contains__("-"):
        start, end = start.split("-")
    end = end.replace("\n","")
    start = int(ip_address(start).packed.hex(), 16)
    end = int(ip_address(end).packed.hex(), 16)
    return [ip_address(ip).exploded for ip in range(start, end)]

# Scan IP address range
        def ScanRange(ranges):
            threads = []                        
            # *-- Scan IP range --*           
            for address in IPsRange(ranges):    
                t = Thread(                     
                    target=__СheckAddrThreaded, 
                    args=(address,)            
                )                               
                threads.append(t)               
                t.start()                       
            for thread in threads:              
                thread.join()
```

At this moment I'm getting some hard time to link the loader.py and scanner.py. There are some changes that I know I need to do but can't figure out exactly what. I would requeste some guidance here

Thanks you all

Answer (score 0):

So you load all possible ips with loader, and process them with scanner correct?

Right. I see. You suggest to import loader.py in scanner.py, but in this case I'd rather make a class that holds related functionality:

```
# Import modules
from .inspection import Request, InspectPaths, InspectContent, PortIsOpen, GetTitle
from ipaddress import ip_address
from threading import Thread
import ipaddress
from os import listdir
from sys import exit

# Scan result
class IP_Scanner():
    def __init__(self, name='', atype='', path='', title=''):
        self.name = name
        self.type = atype
        self.path = path
        self.title = title
        self.processed_range = []

    # Return IPs in IPv4 range, inclusive.
    def process(self, ip):
        try:
            line = "".join(ip.split())
            if ipaddress.ip_interface(line).network:
                self.processed_range.append(line)
                
        except Exception:
            print("INVALID: "+line)
            return 0

    def set_range(self):
        # Select IP ranges from directory
        path = "ip-ranges/"  # Directory path.
        files = listdir(path)  # Get directory files.
        for i, f in enumerate(files):  # Enumerate and
            print(f" [{i + 1}] - {f}")  # print files.
        # *-- Get user input --*
        try:
            file = path + files[int(input("\n [?] Please select country to scan --> ")) - 1]
        except ValueError:
            exit(f" [!] ERROR: Please enter a numerical value!")
        except IndexError:
            exit(f" [!] ERROR: Please enter value from 1 to {len(files)}!")
        else:
            # *-- Read file --*
            with open(file, "r") as ranges_file:  # Open file in reading mode.
                self.range = ranges_file.readlines()  # Read all lines.
            return self.range, file.split("/")[-1]

    # Scan IP address range
    def scan_range(self):
        if self.range:
            threads = []
            # *-- Scan IP range --*
            for address in self.range:
                t = Thread(
                    target=process, #__СheckAddrThreaded, #I'm assuming this is what your process is doing
                    args=(address,)
                )
                threads.append(t)
                t.start()
            for thread in threads:
                thread.join()
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = IP_Scanner()
    x.set_range()
    x.scan_range()
    print('Success on: '+x.processed_range)
```

Many other ways to do this, but this encapsulates the related info into an object so you can run many instances of it in parallel.

For imports from a different folder with **init**.py (or package), see: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/